# How to fix this error that pops up after migrations in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Am new to Laravel ,so been trying to do migrations and this error keeps popping up in the terminal

so after editing my .env file and trying to run php artisan migrate i get the error that i have attached below,i have tried to search the error around,but cant get any meaningful solution

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code and errors. Edit your question, add the actual text (and remove the image if it adds nothing important).

Comment: You need to install or enable pdo_mysql.so php extension. You can google how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the **php-mysql** extension installed on your machine.

You can install this extension with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

Hope this helps! :)